# Google Map Api to Find Only Address Name And Postal Code Of all Shops in City

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing

I am trying to fetch Address Name and Postal Code info of All Shops in specific    City.e.g Amsterdam.
I want to do as same done on this website.
https://www.openingstijden.nl/Noord-Holland/Amsterdam/Drukkerijen/
But i am creating a desktop app.
I was trying this Url
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=nl&key=MY_API_KEY&callback=gmap_draw to fetch but i ain't much deeper in javascript.
If this is correct way of doing this can any one suggest how could i fetch the same results in xml format if not then what is the correct way of fetching the same results as available on this website?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: read the documentation for the c# case. show relevant code in c# else its offtopic in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you provided is JS reference for calling the API.

```
string urlParameters = "";
        //Your code goes here
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA");

        // Add an Accept header for XML format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/xml"); //Keeps returning false
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

        // List data response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;
        //Console.WriteLine(response);
         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               // output xml
               string output = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
             //response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
```

You can edit the URI constructor to include parameters like address/components,key.enter code here
Please refer the documentation for more information.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: Well i think i can't call this in desktop app i have mentioned i am using desktop app using c#